# Auto Adjusting the Size of Images and/or Icons On the Same Line

Tags: html, css, image, icons

Imagine social media icons/images (e.g. Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn) lined up next to each other on the same line.  How can I make the size of the icons/images auto adjust when I add additional icons/images to that line?  Right now they just jump to the next line.  I want it to where, if I add icons/images, they get smaller, so as to stay on the same line; if I take icons/images away, they get larger to fit the width of the container.

Thank you for your help!

Update:

```
            <div class="padding"><a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img class="image" src="images/black_white_facebook.png" alt="Facebook Icon" /></a></div>
            <div class="padding"><a href="http://www.twitter.com"><img class="image" src="images/black_white_twitter.png" alt="Twitter Icon" /></a></div>
            <div class="padding"><a href="http://www.linkedin.com"><img class="image" src="images/black_white_linkedin.png" alt="Linked In Icon" /></a></div>
            <div class="padding"><a href="http://www.wordpress.com"><img class="image" src="images/black_white_wordpress.png" alt="WordPress Icon" /></a></div>
            <div class="padding"><a href="http://www.youtube.com"><img class="image" src="images/black_white_youtube.png" alt="YouTube Icon" /></a></div>
            <div class="padding"><a href="http://www.plus.google.com"><img class="image" src="images/black_white_google_plus.png" alt="Google+ Icon" /></a></div>

        </div><!-- end of icons div -->
```

## icons {margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;}

.image {width: 150px; background-color: white; padding: 2px;}

.padding {display: inline; padding-right: 6px;}

Comment: Can you provide your codes?

Comment: Just posted the code above.  I'm still new to web development, so it's probably not the prettiest code.  Any correction is appreciated.

Comment: Is the social icons need to be in fixed size?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put each content: text, icon in different  and put these  in a line with width and height as you want

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  It doesn't sound like your suggestion would cause the size of the images to automatically adjust in size when images are added or taken away on that line.

Comment: `<div class="text"><a href="http://www.youtube.com"> </a></div> 
<div class="image"><img class="image" src="images/black_white_youtube.png" alt="YouTube Icon" /></div>`

This is my opinion to prevent image jump to next line with css of "text" and "image"